# Communication with Native services

Tags: ios, jailbreak

I found out some services (their name end with "service", but I'm not sure 100% they are actually a service - the main is UIApplicationMain and not XPC service EP) that I want to communicate with them.
Do I need special entitlement for communicating a service? If the service run in different user (eg. root) and I run in the mobile user, can I communicate with him?
I read that launchd is responsible for starting services in iOS, are they any "list" of services when they got triggered they are loaded into the OS? How they got triggered programically?
Can I communicate with lockdownd using an application in the mobile user( like for example I developed an application that do it..)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Each XPC service is unique and implements its own security model fit for its purpose. For example, there could be a helper root service (common on iOS and macOS) that allows non-privileged process to do specific things as root. To do that calling process opens a connection to it, launchd sees that and launches the service. When the work is done the service can be killed as it's not needed any more. They're launched on-demand.

So it doesn't matter that the service is running as root and you're not, that may be the whole purpose. The service itself checks whether the calling process has appropriate privileges to do the calls. The way that iOS and macOS services do that is by checking entitlements of the calling process. When a service receives a connection from calling process it requests the list of entitlements and does the checks by itself. There's no central daemon or kernel driver that does this. Entitlements could contain anything you want.

What that means to you is you need to reverse engineer service by service in order  to understand how you can communicate with them and which privileges they expect from the calling process. Only thing that is centralized here is launchd. launchd plist files define exactly which XPC services there're and what names they have. But the rest is completely up to the specific implementation.